# Can't get dual boot to work with windows 7

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-7

I have tried numerous options but all do not seem to work. The problem is this: The standard ubuntu installer does not recognize my windows installation. When i manually create partitions, grub simply does not start and my pc boots directly into windows. This is the output of gdisk(i read in a couple of posts this could be the problem):

GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.5

```
Partition table scan:  
  MBR: protective  
  BSD: not present  
  APM: not present  
  GPT: present  

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.  
Disk /dev/sda: 1953525168 sectors, 931.5 GiB  
Logical sector size: 512 bytes  
Disk identifier (GUID): 11D43DDE-1B52-DB45-929B-98F1EDA2F5C4  
Partition table holds up to 128 entries  
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 1953525134  
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries  
Total free space is 267629 sectors (130.7 MiB)  

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name  
   1            2048          206847   100.0 MiB   EF00    
   2          468992       978870271   466.5 GiB   0700  
   3       978870272      1953521663   464.8 GiB   0700  Basic data partition
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create your Ubuntu partitions manually and install Ubuntu
2. From a liveCD, run [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)'s `Recommended Repair`. If any problem, indicate the URL that will appear.